# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in pytube

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I'm trying to make a script that downloads videos from youtube, but I keep getting the below error.

```
>>> from pytube import YouTube
>>> vid = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfnCAmr569k")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 92 in __init__ 
    self.descramble()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py",  line 140 in descramble 
    apply_signature(self.player_confing_args, fmt, self.js)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 225 in apply_signature 
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 31 in __init__ var, _ = 
    self.transform_plan[0].split(".")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's may "cipher.py" file's parsing fnc error. Just copy & paste bug fixed source to your "pytube/cipher.py".

related thread : https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/641#issuecomment-665268989